# Why isn't atexit registering in python?

Tags: python, loops, save, pickle, atexit

I have a loop in Tkinter:

```
def main():
    #Global Variables
    windows = []
    buttons = []
    labels = []
    messageboxes = []
    global theme
    theme = 0
    listboxes = []
    global register
    register = []
    global path
    path = ""
    # Lotsa' Code
    Tkinter.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

def save_f():
    global register
    outFile = open('FobbySave.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(register, outFile)
    outFile.close()
global register     
#At Quit
atexit.register(save_f)
```

atexit fails. But when I try to print register it has no problem. save_f worked when I put it in the Tkinter loop, but atexit didn't. So can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

P.S.

### Sorry forgot to write atexit the first time. But it's in my code.

Edit: Orginal code down here

```
import pickle
import atexit
def save_f():
    global register
    outFile = open('Something.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(register, outFile)
    outFile.close()
atexit.register(save_f)
```

Comment: Works for me ... You haven't imported `atexit` in your example ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK turns out the problem was that I needed `atexit.register(save_f)` instead of `atexit.register(save_f())`.

You're not supposed to make a function call!

Answer (score 2):

Your basic script works for me, provided I `import atexit` and set `register` to something.  e.g.:

```
import pickle
import atexit

def save_f():
    outFile = open('Something.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(register, outFile)
    outFile.close()

register = 1
atexit.register(save_f)
```

(note that `global` isn't necessary either).  In cases such as this, you should make sure that you don't have another file named `atexit.py` in the current directory or somewhere else on your `PYTHONPATH` ...

Comment: This is only a part of the code. Register is referenced elsewhere.

Comment: @madprogramer -- you say "atexit can't register it".  What do you mean by that?  does it raise an exception?

Comment: it doesn't do anything. Not even an exception.

Comment: @madprogramer -- How is your script exited?  If you use `os._exit`, then any functions registered by `atexit` won't get run ...

Comment: I'm only using atexit, what else could be the reason?

Comment: @madprogramer -- Can you fix the indentation?  It's tough to see what is going on there ...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I would suggest to try this instead:

```
def main():
    # ... everything in main ...
    Tkinter.mainloop()

def save_f():
    outFile = open('FobbySave.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(register, outFile)
    outFile.close()

#At Quit
atexit.register(save_f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem might have been that you initialize your `atexit` *after* you run the main method. So after the code gets killed (and stops executing) you try to add the `atexit` method.

Comment: register is a list. Is that a problem ?

Comment: @madprogramer: as long as you can pickle register it's ok. But if there is something in the list which is not pickle-safe than it won't work.

Comment: Now I can save by typing in save_f in the interpreter. But it doesn't work automaticly. Here's my basic list:register = [[theme,'theme']]

Comment: What is the value of `theme`? Perhaps you cannot pickle that?

Comment: If you simply add an "save_f()" at the bottom of the script (right before the exit), what result do you get?

Comment: It saves. But only once and when I run the program. If there is a way to update it I could use this one too.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it's not working for you... there has to be something else in your code which is preventing it from working. Perhaps you are killing the app in a different way? Not all exit methods trigger atexit

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this is the issue, but you might want to move the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part to the bottom of the file. The `atexit` will be executed after you've already initialized (and killed) your GUI

Comment: Nope sorry :C Does global also work for functions? If it does I think I can solve the problem.

Comment: Generally you don't really need global that often. The only time you need global is when you do `foo = 'bar'` in a function and `foo` should be global.